# Variables in Linux for a versioning script

Tags: linux, variables, unix, mv

I am working on the deployment of a simple maths application on a Linux VM. The application is a .ear file to be deployed.

I am trying to create a script to version the .ear files being we are deploying so we have `MathsAppV1.ear`, `MathsAppV2.ear` and the next release is `MathsAppV3.ear`. I want to move the file to a backup directory regardless of version number

To hardcode it you can just `mv /opt/deployments/runenvironment/MathsAppV3.ear /home/me/backups`

However I want to move the file into the backups folder in a script regardless of version number something like `MathsAppV$anynumber.ear`

Answer (score 0):

That's basically what you can do. If you specify a variable `anynumber` as

```
anynumber = 4
```

then you can later do

```
mv /opt/deployments/runenvironment/MathsAppV3.ear /home/me/backups/MathsAppV"${anynumber}".ear
```

Note that in principle `$anynumber` is enough, but you have to add the quotes in case $anynumber has whitespace in it, and you should put it in braces to make sure that `$anynumber.ear` doesn't get interpreted as the value of the variable `anynumber.ear`.

**Edit**: if I misunderstood, then this might be what you want:

```
mv /opt/deployments/runenvironment/MathsAppV*.ear /home/me/backups/
```

this will copy all files matching the pattern `MathsAppV*.ear` to `~/backups` under the same name. In hindsight, this case seems to make much more sense.

Comment: That is fantastic thank you very much, was getting muddled

Comment: @O_C, I'm glad it helped. If this is indeed the solution to your problem, please consider marking my answer as accepted.